# Prove the following inequality .

Tags: matrices, inequality

While I was going through matrix norms, I came across the fact that Operator norm of a matrix is less than equal to Frobenius Norm of the matrix. While trying to prove this fact I came across the inequality:-

If 
$$ \sum_{j=1}^{n}x_{j}^{2} = 1$$
 then:
$$
\sum_{j=1}^{n} a_{j}^{2}\geq\left( \sum_{j=1}^{n}a_{j}x_{j}\right)^{2}
$$
($ a_{j}$ and $x_{j}$ are real numbers for $j\in\{1,2,3 \ldots\}$)

I want to know if the inequality is true or not. If true what is the proof. So far I have not been able to find any counter example.

Comment: Cauchy-Schwarz?

Comment: Its cauchy-shwarz inequality

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's immediate with Cauchy-Schwarz inequality !

$$
\left( \sum_{j=1}^{n}a_{j}x_{j}\right)^{2} \leq \left(\sum_{j=1}^{n} a_{j}^{2} \right)\left(\sum_{j=1}^{n} x_{j}^{2} \right) = \sum_{j=1}^{n} a_{j}^{2} 
$$

in the last step I used $$ \sum_{j=1}^{n} x_{j}^{2} =1$$